# Spatial query - poor performance, not using index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

I'm trying to find locations within some distance from given coordinates. On a table with about 32k records query takes about 2 seconds - which is way too slow, imo.

It is doing a clustered index scan, which is logical - it has to calculate distance for every location.. However, I still think this should be faster over a data set this small. I do have spatial index defined, however it's not used, and query fails if I'm forcing it.

Most of the time (~86%) is spent on Filter that calculates the distance - so I'm looking for a ways to optimize that, and I need some help here..

The query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Venue
WHERE (Coordinates.STDistance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-113.512245 51.498212)', 4326)) / 1000) <= 100
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are SQL Server 2008 Spatial Data features useful for mapping queries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343293/are-sql-server-2008-spatial-data-features-useful-for-mapping-queries)

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1000 in the StDistance clause? Can this be calculated elsewhere?

Comment: Changing to WHERE Coordinates.STDistance(geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-113.512245 51.498212)', 4326)) <= 100000  will allow the use of a spatial index as a primary filter rather than table scan. You might still require an explicit index hint if you're using SQL 2008 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One old approach is to use a BOX firxt.

From your point, make two points on opposite ends of the box. +R/+R and -R/-R from the center.

Then you can filter - a point has to be in this box AND in the circle you describe.

The box check can run on the index and kills most elements.

Simple school geometry. You draw a rectangular box around the circle you describe.

Your current approach can not use the index because the index does not contain the fields.

ALTERNATIVELY: DRAW A CIRCLE - do not use a distance calculation. Draw a circle. With points.

Or read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311363/my-application-is-about-asp-net-using-linq-and-remote-mssql-my-connection-is-be which is the same issue you ask.

Comment: I kind of did.. Using STBuffer.